# Change the form fields to url

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I need to change the form to a single link instead of post as below:

Instead of http://example.hu/search.php?product=shoes

I want the form to lead user only to http://example.hu/products/shoes

I have fixed the rewrite and everything. Only I need the help with the form in the homepage. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Learn about Url rewriting

Comment: lol why can't you explicitly set it in the form?

Comment: This question makes no sense. Maybe show some code of the problem and we could help

Comment: try searching for url rewriting using htaccess for example. this seems nice: 
http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the form up a little. Instead of using the action parameter on `<form>` to send the user along, instead you'll need to drop the form tag and do some javascript trickery to make the url like you want. Here's an example that uses jquery, but it could also easily be done in vanilla JS. http://jsfiddle.net/7czFq/

Comment: why would you do something like that in javascript?

Comment: Because his question was about directing users to the correct url using form elements.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question was this:

Just go to this form action + name using javascript when submit is pressed, like this:

```
<form>
<div><input type="text" placeholder="Search for a something..." name="q">
<button type="submit" onclick="window.location.href = this.form.action + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementsByName('q')[0].value); return false; ">Search</button></div>
</form>
```

The form will send user to a URL like http://localhost.hu/search/q/